# Python damages mported csv file through cursor.execute with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I did import of csv file in MySQL database by means of mysql-connection in python, but, something went wrong and I completely don't know what exactly and how to fix it.

For example, consider last and pre-last columns (1) - ShortTermScore, (2) - LongTermScore and (3) RequestedAmount column.
[image]

[image]

after that code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector as mysql

db = mysql.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "sgfgdg",
    passwd = "Psswrd"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)

cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb")

cursor.execute("""USE testdb""")
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_task (Project INT, OrderDate DATE NOT NULL, orderid INT, ClientID INT,IsRepeat INT,IsBlocked INT,IsManual INT,AutoDecision INT,ManualApprove INT,IsLoan INT,ShortTermAmount INT,ShortTermPeriod INT,LongTermAmount INT,LongTermPeriod INT,RequestedAmount INT,RequestedPeriod INT,LoanSum INT,Period INT,ShortTermScore FLOAT,LongTermScore FLOAT)""")

cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/man/TTF.csv' INTO TABLE test_task FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ")

cursor.execute("""SELECT *  FROM test_task""")
head_rows = cursor.fetchmany(size=6)
print(head_rows)
```

I got this

```
(0, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0) <- I assume this is header
(1, None, 1794004, 1040307, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 700, 12, 0, 0.0, 0.085)
(1, None, 1794005, 1305335, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 900, 26, 0, 0.0, 0.017)
(1, None, 1794021, 1174614, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 500, 20, 0.0, 500.0)
(1, None, 1794032, 1356306, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0.0, 750.0)
(1, None, 1794057, 1120819, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 168, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Why 0.085 and 0.017 from first and second row respectively only in last column?

What the 500.0 and 750.0 in third and fourth row last column instead of 0.926 and 0.679 respectively?

Why 700 and 900 from first and second row respectively instead of 6700 and 1900?

And why whole column with date (OrderId) just disappear at all?))

That's just horrible... And nowhere I see the same situations...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12yPqkyeS8hfD1sbBSwFKLPqeoa4Ycwdt/view?usp=sharing  - initial excel file.

I convert it in csv with command

```
soffice --headless --convert-to csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":44,34,76 /home/user/Desktop/TTFfw.xlsx
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nzas2LJ-Ol6Fr868xe11YrwjKwxUpoSA/view?usp=sharing  -  csv file

Please, help me.

Comment: Please add your csv file as text to the question.

Comment: Done. But there is nothing strange with it.

Comment: It's strangely unlike a csv file and of no value for resolving  this issue - nb Although optional I would add a lines terminated by clause to the load data infile